# how to write a query that returns the id 10 of the most senior employee in each department? (postgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

1. How to write a query that returns the id 10 of the most senior employee in each department?
2. And a query that returns the id of employees who are older than their leader

I have a data table **employee**

**id integer** - id employee

**name char** - name employee

**department_id integer**- id of the department in which the employee works

**chief_flg boolean** - flag that the employee is in a leadership position

**birth_dt date** - Date of Birth

**salary integer** - employee salary

I think here you need to apply the **max** function and maybe **limit** and **offset**?
How to write 2 request data correctly?

```
SELECT MAX (e.id)
FROM employee e
GROUP BY birth_dt
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 9;
-------------------
SELECT MAX(o.id)
FROM employee o
INNER JOIN employee o
ON o.department_id = e.department_id
GROUP BY birth_dt
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 9;
```

Comment: The only way to learn SQL is practice, practice, practice. Have you created the tables and inserted data? Do your queries return the expected result or not?

Comment: `MAX(id)` can't be what you want.

Comment: LIMIT but no ORDER BY will give you 10 random rows.

Comment: top 10 per department :: consider `RANK() OVER()`::  check the documentation perhaps?

Comment: @adamantium you don't need offset function when you have to `Limit 10 rows each department`  (in the descending order of `birth_dt`)

Answer (score 0):

> How to write a query that returns the id 10 of the most senior
> employee in each department?

```
SELECT e1.id
FROM employee e1
WHERE e1.chief_flg = false AND e1.id IN (
SELECT e2.id
FROM employee e2
WHERE e2.department_id = e1.department_id
ORDER BY e2.birth_dt DESC
LIMIT 10
)
ORDER BY e1.department_id;
```

> And a query that returns the id of employees who are older than their
> leader

```
SELECT e1.id
FROM employee e1
INNER JOIN employee e2
ON e1.department_id = e2.department_id
AND e2.chief_flg = true
AND e1.birth_dt > e2.birth_dt;
```